# D3 Force Layout with Links Distances Based Off Data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am building this [**force layout**](https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph) in D3 Observable. Already looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184042/how-to-increase-the-length-of-a-link-in-d3-force-layout).

I want the link length to be commensurate with the value passed from the data. So if these are my values:

```
[1, 0.92, 0.89, 0.84, 0.83, 0.82, 0.76, 0.75, 0.74, 0.71, 0.69, 0.66, 0.65, 0.6, 0.58, 0.57, 0.54, 0.53, 0.47, 0.37, 0.35, 0.26, 0.14, 0.05, 0]
```

Then these nodes would be farther and farther away from the root (or closer and closer, doesn't matter, just needs to be consistent). Instead, this is what I get:

[image]

As you can see these are randomly placed from the root. Here is the relevant **link code**:

```
const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.id))
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(function(d) {return d.value;}).strength(1))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
```

I am parsing the **value** from the data. The values are the ones above in the array. How can I get my D3 code to draw the link distance based on the magnitude of the value passed?

Comment: Do you want the nodes to be at the right distance prior to initializing the force simulation (or on initialization of the force simulation) - or do you want them to end up at the right distance later, during the simulation (as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38253560/7106086))

Comment: Hmm interesting. I would take either approach as long as the correct distances are established within a few seconds of rendering the visual, and showing good separation between nodes.